# Вычисление времени до Нового Года

Tags: php

Хелоу! Мне хотелось сделать на php скрипт, который будет считать сколько осталось до Нового Года (в днях, часах, минутах и секундах). Буду признателен если подкинете код.

Comment: у меня ощущение что хешкод вместо гугл поиска используется.
тут ведьименно для тебя напишут код, а то что гугл предлагает тысячи скриптов в поиске, уже написанных, и даже с описанием...

Эх куда катится молодежь, что будет через 5 лет.
задает кто-то вопрос, и ему сразу и код и документацию дай, и вместо него поработай а он бабосы получит:)

Comment: @Shrek ну в в сети примеров правда много, но действительно правильно подскажут только люди, а не гугл

Comment: а скрипты у нас уже лет 10 пишут машины, не знал, не знал.

Comment: Если ты принимаешь все так дословно, то я ничего поделать с этим не могу.

Comment: [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval)

Comment: Странно, а не лучше ли иcпользовать JS?

Comment: @culebre, тихо! а то он сейчас подумает, подумает, и попросит на JS написать!
Ибо [таймер обратного отсчета][1] не найдет!

  [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/36366/таймер-обратного-отсчета

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запостю тоже, так как когда начал писать - ответов не было... не пропадать же труду :)

```
$currentYear = date('Y'); // получаем текущий год

$newYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $currentYear + 1); // высчитываем дату Нового Года
$seconds = $newYear - time();

$days = 0; $hours = 0; $minutes = 0;
$oneMinute = 60;
$oneHour = 60 * $oneMinute;
$oneDay = $oneHour * 24;

if ($seconds / $oneDay > 0) {
    $days = (int)($seconds / $oneDay);
    $seconds -= $days * $oneDay;
}

if ($seconds / $oneHour > 0) {
    $hours = (int)($seconds / $oneHour);
    $seconds -= $hours * $oneHour;
}

if ($seconds / $oneMinute > 0) {
    $minutes = (int)($seconds / $oneMinute);
    $seconds -= $minutes * $oneMinute;
}

printf('К Новому Году осталось: %02d дней %02d часов %02d минут и %02d секунд', $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Comment: А как у вас решается описанная вами проблема временной зоны? =))

Comment: а в таймстампе нету таймзоны. Там всегда время по гринвичу :)
есть один таймстамп, отнимаем второй и получаем чистое количество секунд в интересующем нас интервале.

Comment: Тогда я не вижу принципиальной разницы в коде. Че-то туплю. Ну, в смысле, в ЭТОМ вопросе.

Comment: А тут и нету особой разницы с **вашим** кодом :). Я его запостил потому что его написал, на момент написания ответов не было.

А по поводу таймзоны это относится к ответу @Palmervan

PS: Уже вечер, возможно я просто чего то не понимаю :)

Answer (score 3):

Опять ты...

```
<?php
$ny = mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, 2012);
$timeUntilNY = $ny - time();
$days = floor($timeUntilNY/3600/24);

$hours = floor($timeUntilNY%(3600*24)/3600);

$mins = floor(($timeUntilNY%3600)/60);

$secs = $timeUntilNY%60;
printf('До нового года: %d дней %d часов %d минут %d секунд ',$days,$hours,$mins,$secs);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$realtime = mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 01, 2012);
$futuretime = $realtime - time();
echo date("До нового года: j дней h часов i минут s секунд", $futuretime);
```

Comment: это не правильный код. Потому что у вас будет разница в количество часов вашей таймЗоны. На крайняк можно воспользоватся gmdate но и он будет работать только для периода < месяца до Нового года.

Comment: Да я уже увидел, погрешность есть... пара минут осталось до конца рабочего дня, нет времени продумать)

Comment: Ага... И работать будет только для декабря. Если это запустить в ноябре, то все гикнется.

Comment: @knes, ну я это и имел ввиду
"но и он будет работать только для периода < месяца до Нового года."

просто чето словесный ступор был при попытке это описать :)

Comment: Вот я в эту фразу и не вкурил =)))

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

```
$date = date_create(); //текущая дата

    $datka = date_format($date, 'd.n.Y');
    $newYear = 12; //последний месяц года
    $arr = explode('.', $datka);


    $month = []; //здесь будет количество дней, в каждом месяце текущего года

    for($i = 1; $i <=12; $i++) {
         $month[$i] = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, $arr[0], $arr[2]));
    }

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($month);
    echo '</pre>';

    $ostatok = 0;

    for($j = $arr[1]; $j <=12; $j++) { //$arr[1]отсчёт начинается с текущего месяца (складываются все дни)
        $ostatok= $ostatok + $month[$j];
    }

    echo 'Количество дней до Нового года: ' . ($ostatok - $arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('L');
if($date == 1){
    $endYear = 366-date('z');
    echo 'До конца года осталось '.$endYear.' дней.';
}else{
    $endYear = 365 - date('z');
    echo 'До конца года осталось '.$endYear.' дней.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date_create();
$ny = date_create('1 jan next year');
$diff = date_diff($today, $ny);
echo $diff->format('%a дней');
```

format [можно поменять на нужный](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Старайтесь писать универсальный код, и чтобы он не выдавал ошибок